# How to load a related entity after call AddAsync without making another roundtrip to the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

How to load a related entity after calling `AddAsync`?

I have a repository method that looks like this

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

    try
    {
        entity.CreatedOn = entity.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        var newEntity = await Entities.AddAsync(entity);
        var newEntityToRet = newEntity.Entity;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        
        return newEntityToRet;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException exception)
    {
        //ensure that the detailed error text is saved in the Log
        throw new Exception(GetFullErrorTextAndRollbackEntityChanges(exception), exception);
    }
}
```

Trying to insert an Order for example that looks like this, and only passing the `StatusId` and the `TradingActionId` makes the Add safe

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
    public int TradingActionId { get; set; }
    public TradingAction TradingAction { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}

var order = new Order
{
       TradingActionId = 1,
       StatusId = 1,
       Notes = source.Notes,
       Price = source.Price,
       Symbol = source.Symbol,
       Quantity = source.Quantity,
       CreatedOn = dateTimeNow,
       UpdatedOn = dateTimeNow,
       UpdatedBy = "test",
       CreatedBy = "test"
 };
```

The problem with this is that if I need to return the new entity with certain navigation properties. My following approach doesn't work but shows the idea of what I need to save the instance and at the same time return the child properties.

```
public virtual async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity, string[] include = null)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

    try
    {
        entity.CreatedOn = entity.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        var newEntity = await Entities.AddAsync(entity);
        var newEntityToRet = newEntity.Entity;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        if(include != null)
        {
            foreach (var navProp in include)
            {
                try
                {
                    var memberEntry = _context.Entry(newEntityToRet).Member(navProp);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    throw;
                }

                if (memberEntry is DbCollectionEntry collectionMember)
                    collectionMember.Load();

                if (memberEntry is DbReferenceEntry referenceMember)
                    referenceMember.Load();
            }
        }
        
        return newEntityToRet;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException exception)
    {
        //ensure that the detailed error text is saved in the Log
        throw new Exception(GetFullErrorTextAndRollbackEntityChanges(exception), exception);
    }
}
```

The version I am using of EF Core is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.4

Any suggestions of how to create the generic repo method and return the data needed without making another roundtrip to the database?

Comment: The problem is that all your generic code running outside of Db server. As soon as you call SaveChanges the query string is sent fo DB server and by default it returns newly created record. All your changes should be done before calling SaveChanges and the most include staff dependens on primary key. But PK in the most cases autogenerated and could be obtained only after saving. The only way to save trip is good old Ado.Net and  stored procedure or text query. Althoug you still can call it using EF. But it is a different strory.

Comment: @Sergey the FK ids can be assigned before and that will create the relation, in my scenario, I am specifying the Ids because are used as reference data

Comment: You can do this for Add data. You can create the whole bunch parents and children and then will be saved and automatically genereate all keys. But I don't know how you can iclude something new in update. If you have this already you don't need to include it. If you don't how you tell EF to update and select  some new data from db in the same time?

Comment: EF creates an sql query to  the server and we don't have much control.

Comment: You could use `DbContext.FindAsync(primaryKey)` method. It'll fetch the instance you're looking for only if the object isn't already tracked.

Comment: @Sergey with eager loading you have it, that is the approach I am trying to do on the second code of the repo, I am just asking if there is a way to load it and at the same time to avoid that roundtrip, but my solutions is not working

Comment: @RamenTurismo I agree, but in that case I will be loading the references Status and TradingAction in advance to track them with my Order entity, and that is another rountrip to the database to find those elements

Comment: @Zinov Do you have these objects in advance before calling the method? If you don't, then how do you expect them to be populated w/o database trip(s)?

Comment: @Sergey Even if you had an entity graph, once you are inside the method, you really cannot know what properties (navigation or not) the entity might have, since `TEntity` doesn't represent any specific entity. But you can load the related data (parent reference or child collection) explicitly with `Load` or `LoadAsync` method (EF Core has complete infrastructural support for such loading from inside generic methods) which OP is already trying to use. I think OP is trying to avoid writing new queries to fetch related data, not to avoid a database trip :)

Comment: @Zinov If you wanted to mean only to avoid new LINQ queries and not to actually avoid database trip, then it would be better if you could mention that adding an `Edit` to the post, and also modify the title/post to reflect that. This will clarify the intention of the post and not confuse other members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inserting a new entity you can always load its related entities explicitly with the `Load()` or `LoadAsync()` method. But even though it doesn't execute a typical `LINQ` method/query (like the one you would write to fetch some related data), EF needs to submit new query to the database for each explicit loading. Therefore, it really doesn't save you any database trip.

Since you are already trying to use the `Load()` method in your code, I'm assuming your intention is just to avoid writing the new `LINQ` queries (required to fetch the related data), and not to avoid a database trip. If that is the case, you can try something like bellow -

```
public async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity, params string[] includes)
{
    entity.CreatedOn = entity.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    
    var newEntry = Entities.Add(entity);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();    // trip to database

    foreach (var navProp in includes)
    {
        if (newEntry.Navigation(navProp).Metadata.IsCollection())
        {
            await newEntry.Collection(navProp).LoadAsync();    // trip to database
        }
        else
        {
            await newEntry.Reference(navProp).LoadAsync();    // trip to database
        }
    }
    return newEntry.Entity;
}
```

which you can use like -

```
var addedOrder = await orderRepository.AddAsync(order, "Status", "TradingAction");
```

Notice -

1. I'm using `params` to pass one or more parameters
2. To add/insert a new entity use the `Add` or `Attach` method. Unless you are dealing with value generators like `SequenceHiLo`, you really don't need to use the `AddAsync` method. For details - [`AddAsync<TEntity>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_AddAsync__1___0_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

A type-safe implementation would be -

```
public async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
{
    entity.CreatedOn = entity.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    
    var newEntry = Entities.Add(entity);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();    // trip to database

    foreach (var navProp in includes)
    {
        string propertyName = navProp.GetPropertyAccess().Name;

        if (newEntry.Navigation(propertyName).Metadata.IsCollection())
        {
            await newEntry.Collection(propertyName).LoadAsync();    // trip to database
        }
        else
        {
            await newEntry.Reference(propertyName).LoadAsync();    // trip to database
        }
    }
    return newEntry.Entity;
}
```

so that you can pass the navigation properties like -

```
var addedOrder = await orderRepository.AddAsync(order, p => p.Status, p => p.TradingAction);
```